# Python: printing dictionary of dictionary with variables

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to retrieve some values from a dictionary, should be fairly easy.

For whatever reason, I cannot use a variable to retrieve a value.

I have two dictionaries, one with a mapping of uids -> usernames (via getent passwd), and a second dictionary which contains a dictionary for each key, basically:

```
dMap = { 12345678: 'username' }
qDict['12345678'] = {'used': '4204224',  'grace': 'none', 'quota': '5242880'}
```

Obviously there are many more values for both dictionaries, but the structure I've shown is the basic concept.

They key for qDict would be a uid (which should be mapped via the dMap dictionary)

Where I'm having trouble is the following:

```
for k,v in dMap.items():
    print 'Key: ',k
    print qDict[k]
```

When I run the script, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 156, in ?
    main() 
  File "./test.py", line 98, in main
    print qDict[k]
KeyError: 26617862
```

If I comment out the:  print qDict[k]    line above, and only print the value of k, the key names are printed without issue. I can also reference the dictionary outside of the for loop with an actual keyname (12345678):

```
print dMap[26617862]         # this works!
print qDict['26617862']      # this works!      #NOTE BELOW
```

What I'm trying to do is just have the for loop print the dictionary for the given keyname, kind of printing the dictionary of a dictionary...

What I think the problem is that (if you look at the #NOTE BELOW line) I need to somehow present the dictionary (qDict) with the properly formatted variable.

Is there something I'm missing here, or is there an easier way to do this?

PS: I've also tried the for loop with dMap.keys(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The keys in `dMap` are integers, but in `qDict` the keys are strings.

You need to convert your integer `k` to a string before using it as a key in `qDict`:

```
for k in dMap:
    print 'Key: ',k
    print qDict[str(k)]
```

Comment: Yes, this was exactly it!

I'm recently coming from perl, and I don't remember these same types of issues, but I could be wrong...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You built the two dictionaries using different types for the keys.  One dict has an integer key and the other has a string key.

As @Mark Byers said, you can convert the integer to a string to do the lookup.

However, I recommend you instead build `qDict` with integer keys.  Wherever your code is that builds `qDict`, wrap the key in `int()` to force it to be an integer key.

Either way will work, really.  But if `dMap` has `int` keys and `qDict` has `str` keys, there are some keys possible in `qDict` that cannot appear in `dMap`, and if the two are to match, it's better if they just have the same type of key.  And `int` should be slightly more efficient, so if your program scales up large, it's the better choice.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am going to convert both keys to a common format. In this case, I'm going to use string because I need to trim some garbage from my input files which I used to populate the dictionaries.